# Jenkins shared pipeline lib - get build status

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

I am trying to build a reusable library for a Jenkins pipeline project, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the build status as well as set it. If I use a Jenkinsfile or a vars script, it works, but what I'm interested in is using the src/ library structure.

I've managed to get other stuff working such as regular git, sh, node, stage steps by using an interface but I cannot get the 'currentBuild' wrapper to work. I tried lots of things and I think I need to use RunWrapper but I can't figure it out.

I used to be able to use the following block before in my Pipeline script directly, and now I want to move it to my lib:
`currentBuild.result = "UNSTABLE"`

Comment: Can you post a minimal sample code? I think `currentBuild.result` works in a `vars` script at least.

Comment: @zett42 I know it works in a vars script, what I want is to use it in a src/ Groovy file. That's my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

while using src i believe you call the file using new key word. have you tried passing the script element from JenkinsFile

**Example JenkinsFile**

```
@Library('somalib@version')
import com.mypackage.MyClass //this is inside src folder
new MyClass(this).execute() //pass this to constructor
```

**your MyClass looks like**

```
package com.mypackage

class MyClass {
    this.script
    MyClass(script){
        this.script = script
    }

    execute(){
        script.node('nodeName'){
            script.echo(script.currentBuild.result)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have managed to get it working with a similar solution, by passing the context to the constructor. But now I'm passing that context between a lot of classes and I feel like it's not a good idea but I might be mistaken.<br> On that topic, I am not sure why passing the context to another class from MyClass results in a CPS error. But if I pass it via a method it works. Is this the normal behavior? This is the first time I've have to do context switching so I'm trying to write good code while I'm at it :)

Comment: the Best approach is to keep the dsl method calls in the vars folder, the content inside execute method can go to vars and call script.thenewVarFile form execute method by that you can eliminate the frequent context  calls

Comment: I need to create a library so more teams can use the various functions. Keeping all the stuff inside vars/ is not an option for me since it's not flexible enough. I will keep working on it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: also refer https://github.com/mkobit/jenkins-pipeline-shared-library-example

Comment: That example is nice but I followed a different one which I think is more generic: https://github.com/kuper-adrian/jenkins-shared-library-example